# Search multiple files in subdirectories for each string in a list and return a list of strings found

Tags: batch-file, find, findstr

I have a folder with ~20,000 files in multiple subfolders. The files have varying extensions, but their content is all text. I also have a text list of ~500 names. I'd like to search all the files for each name in the text list, one at a time, for the purpose of determining if that name appears in any of the files.

The desired output is a text list of ~500 lines (or however many names were searched), each with a 1 (if the name was found, regardless of how many times) or a 0 (if not). The order of this file would match the input text list.

e.g.,

```
searchstring.txt
   nameA
   nameB
   nameC

searchfolder
  subfolder1
      file.abc    (references name A)
      file2.xyz   (no references)
  subfolder2
      file.xyz     (no references)
      file3.xyz    (references name A)
  subfolder3
      file4.abc     (no references)
      file5.xyz    (references name A, name C)

result.txt
   1
   0
   1
```

Ideally the search would be called be with a batch file with commands available on Windows 7 and up. The environment may not have Admin permissions.

Comment: While I have no doubt that this could be done in pure batch by some of the batch experts here, would a PowerShell solution be acceptable?

Comment: If a name appears in more than one file, do you want to know all of the files that it appears in?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Powershell may not be available in the environments in which this search will occur. 
-- If a name appears in more than one file, do you want to know all of the files that it appears in? --
I can't think of a way to do that and preserve the number of lines in the file. The boolean output will ultimately be pasted into a spreadsheet adjacent to a column that exactly matches the text list. The goal is really just to determine if the name appears in any of the files. Question modified to nix that ask.

Comment: What environments will it be executed in? Windows 7 and later have PowerShell included with the OS.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, the machines will be client-owned at times, the exact configurations vary and some may prevent access to PowerShell. A PowerShell solution would probably be fine; I just believe the probability will be higher with batch.

Comment: A [tag:powershell] solution, _(even run from a batch file)_, is my suggestion. Using it directly on a export from Excel and updating it so that Excel can get the results already in a new column, makes sense.

Comment: @Compo, I may use this solution for other purposes, I'd rather not tie it to Excel. It's no bother to copy a column into a text file and another one back.

Comment: @Alex, it wouldn't have to be tied to Excel, if you work with a CSV exported from it, read the column with the names, search and return the results as an additional field on that CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the information you have provided in your edit, the following single line may work for you.

As a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@For /F UseBackDelims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ("searchstring.txt")Do @(FindStr /LIMPS "%%~A" "searchfolder\*.*">Nul&&(Echo 1)||Echo 0)>>"result.txt"
```

Entered at the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) prompt:

```bat
For /F UseBackDelims^=^ EOL^= %A In ("searchstring.txt")Do @(FindStr /LIMPS "%~A" "searchfolder\*.*">Nul&&(Echo 1)||Echo 0)>>"result.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly on my test files. Can you describe how it works?

Comment: @Alex, I'd prefer that you start by looking up each of the commands and work through it yourself. `For /?` `FindStr /?`. Add to that, the conditional statements `&&` and `||` which essentially mean _if the previous command was successful_ and _if the previous command was unsuccessful_ respectively, and you should get it.